# is it possible to call Java functions from aiml?

Tags: java, aiml

I am creating a chatbot using Java and program ab. In few places I can’t answer the questions directly, I have to process something or call a web service and process the result and then reply back. In such cases how to include the result of my java function to the responses in the aiml.

Say,

```
User: What is the price of the product A?
Bot: The price of product A is $50
```

In the above example, $50 is not going to be same always. I have to take that in run time. So how to solve this problem?

```
**AIML:**

<category>
    <pattern>WHAT IS THE PRICE OF THE *</pattern>
    <template>The price of <star/> is $<call some function price(productA)> 
    </template>
</category>

**JAVA:**

public int price(String product){
   // gets the product price
   // do the conversion 
   // apply discount
   return price;
}
```

Please someone help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically AIML extensions are implemented as an extension tag. So you wouldn't call a programming language method/function directly from AIML script. In the AB documentation you can find more details about implementing this kind of functionality [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/program-ab/wikis/ExtendingAIML.wiki). Below is the relevant text with an updated link to `PCAIMLProcessorExtension` found in a [forked project](https://github.com/lumenrobot/program-ab) on GitHub. There a couple of practical examples on of working extensions can be found.

> **AIMLProcessorExtension**
>
> Program AB defines a Java Interface called AIMLProcessorExtension that
>   you can use to define new AIML tags.
>
> A class implementing AIMLProcessorExtension must provide:
>
> - a Set of tag names.
> - a function to recursively evaluate the XML parse tree for each node associated with a new tag.
>
> The Program AB source
>   includes a sample implementation of this interface called
>   [PCAIMLProcessorExtension](https://github.com/lumenrobot/program-ab/blob/master/src/main/java/org/alicebot/ab/PCAIMLProcessorExtension.java), which defines a collection of tags
>   simulating a contacts database.

Comment: Thanks! But is there any tutorial or reference material or any documentation on how to use AIMLProcessorExtension? I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Updated the answer with a link to the example extension you seek.

Comment: Thanks! can you also please look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43463390/aimlprocessorextension-tag-not-working-in-aiml

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple and general option, you can keep a keyword to be used in switch later on, e.g.

AIML template will have a keyword for operation,

```
<category>
   <pattern>WHAT IS THE PRICE OF THE *</pattern>
   <template>PRICE,The price of <star/> is,<star/> </template>
```

And update java code like:

```
String response  = aimlResponse(request);
String [] responseComponents = reponse.parse(",");
String method = responseComponents[0];

//Then use switch, also apply size check on array after parsing in case of response with No keywords

Switch method:
{
case PRICE:
//here add the price to response string
String price = price(responseComponents[2]);
response = responseComponents[1]+ price;
break;
}
```

Comment: What if there are two or more components in the response on which the function to be called depends? something like : Is the room X door open? here room makes sense as function related to room has to be called but X also makes sense because which room is it to check for is important too.

Comment: Just append all required elements separated by a comma and in the program you can parse them. Like in the above example, we know for this response, responseComponents[0] is method, you can store custom element at [1], in this case the room number.