# AIMLProcessorExtension: tag not working in aiml

Tags: java, aiml

I am trying to create my own tag in `aiml` using program tab. The tag is not working. What is the problem?

Java code:

```
public class AIMLExtension implements AIMLProcessorExtension{
  public Set<String> extensionTagNames = Utilities.stringSet("check");
  @Override
  public Set<String> extensionTagSet() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return extensionTagNames;
  }

  private String contactId(Node node, ParseState ps) {
    return "Success :P";
  }

  @Override
  public String recursEval(Node node, ParseState ps) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        String nodeName = node.getNodeName();
        if (nodeName.equals("check"))
            return contactId(node, ps);
        else return (AIMLProcessor.genericXML(node, ps));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
  }
}
```

AIML code: I am getting `I have no answer`for the below code.

```
<category>
  <pattern>CHECKING EXTENSION</pattern>
  <template>RESTCALL <check> </template>
</category>
```

AIML code : I am getting `RESTCALL <check/>` itself for the below code.

```
<category>
  <pattern>CHECKING EXTENSION</pattern>
  <template>RESTCALL <check/> </template>
</category>
```

Comment: were you able to find any solution?

Comment: No, I haven't found any solution for this problem. Luckily for my project that was not that important.

Comment: hi kavipriya. Did u find a solution for this ?

Comment: No.. I couldn't make it work.. I shifted to other project and left that.. so haven't tried again.. please let me know if you get any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and after a long time of trying different solutions I could find the solution for the problem why you get the no answer from java side when you put your made up tag  in your aiml file, and instead the tag is converted automatically to  tag.

It was an issue of getting the dependencies wight in the pom.xml file. you should use the dependencies used in the following [pom.xml](https://github.com/lumenrobot/program-ab/blob/master/pom.xml). This pom.xml is from the same [repository](https://github.com/lumenrobot/program-ab/blob/master/src/main/java/org/alicebot/ab/PCAIMLProcessorExtension.java) where you found the example of AIMLExtension.

I added the following lines to the properties in my pom.xml:

```
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
    <httpclient.version>4.2.5</httpclient.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
```

and the following lines to the dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
     </dependency>
```

You should make sure that you have defined a class to write the new aiml files as shown in ([3.1. Adding Custom Patterns](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/library/java-aiml-chatbot-example/)) before running and testing your chat bot

Answer (score -1):

Explore program-ab and see how its tags work. I created a tag by replicating code for person tag in program ab code.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  explain or put your code.